# Query to select records between two dates based on the year you are in

Tags: sql, ms-access

This query is supposed to display all records between two dates that fall in different years.
i.e All records between the **beginning** of **August** of the **previous** year and the end of **July** of the **current** year. I have used the query below last year but when I opened the database yesterday, I see "No records"
This is clearly wrong as I know there is record in the database. I can see there is a problem in the `WHERE ((Year(DateAdd('m',-7,[CommissionDate]))=Year(Date())))` as the new year kicks in. I intend to return all records from the beginning of august of previous year to end of July of current year!
Can I amend the query for it to work correctly?

```
SELECT IIf(Month([CommissionDate]) In (8,9,10),"Q1",IIf(Month([CommissionDate]) In 
(11,12,1),"Q2",IIf(Month([CommissionDate]) In (2,3,4),"Q3","Q4"))) AS Quarter, *
FROM tblAllRecords
WHERE ((Year(DateAdd('m',-7,[CommissionDate]))=Year(Date())))
ORDER BY tblAllRecords.CommissionDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
SELECT 
    Format(DateAdd("m", 5, [CommissionDate]), "\Qq") As Quarter,
    *
FROM 
    tblAllRecords
WHERE 
    [CommissionDate] Between 
        DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, 8, 1) And 
        DateSerial(Year(Date()), 8, 0) 
ORDER BY 
    tblAllRecords.CommissionDate DESC;
```

Comment: Superb. All works well. @Gustav, will this also work for the beginning of the cycle i.e from 01/08/2021 to 31/07/2021 since its when the new record period begins?. I am hoping this behavior repeats every year. Happy new year!